# Dispatcher not working in asynch mode

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

Why does this work:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Thread.Sleep(500) );
```

but this does not work?

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsynch(() => Thread.Sleep(500) );
```

A step by step debug correctly enters the first method as expected but never enters the second one.
Is there anthing needed before calling the `InvokeAsynch` method?

Context is a `WPF` application.

Answer (score 0):

Because it´s an async method you have to await it to return:

```
await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Mymethod );
```

Or use the syntax below if you are not in a "async context":

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Mymethod).ContinueWith(x => { DoSomething_here });
```

Comment: It does not seem to do the trick.
If I run:
 await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Mymethod() );

MyMethod code is never run and the thread waits indefinitely.

Comment: I think you have to add your method as a refereence, not invoke it like: `await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Mymethod);`

Answer (score 0):

Result of `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(...)` is a [DispatcherOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcheroperation(v=vs.110).aspx). It's pretty much a wrapper around a Task that was submitted to the Dispatcher queue.
So to get the behavior I believe you're expecting you can use the following code:

```
var dispatcherOperation = Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Thread.Sleep(500) );
dispatcherOperation.Wait();
```

or you can `await` this object as it has `TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter()` method.